# How to remove the crosshair with number thing hanging around on the canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I accidentally placed this crosshair-with-a-number-thing on the canvas. **How do I remove it?**

Also, what is it and how do I create another one if I wish to do so? Thank you!

[image: Crosshair Thing]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### That is the Color Sampler Tool

You can find it under the Eyedropper Tool, which it behaves exactly like, except that it saves your selection. You can see the sampled colors in the Info panel (you can hit the eydropper dropdown on specific samples to see different readout values). You can save up to 4 different samples in CS6 and I believe up to 10 samples in CC.

To remove *all* of your samples simply hit the "Clear" button in the top bar (with the Color Sampler tool active). To remove a single sample you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the sample (again, with the Color Sampler tool active).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's under Preferences —>Painting Cursors. You've chosen Precise. Click around on the radio buttons until you get the one you want.

Comment: It's actually the color sampler tool.

Comment: @Cai ooh, is it? good job, then. I thought it looked like the Precise cursor.

Comment: It looks exactly like the precise cursor, it's the little number next to it and the info panel that gives it away :-)

Comment: @Cai how do I remove it, then? Thanks!